# fstream !fail() and is_open()

Tags: c++, fstream

I want to write data to a file via `fstream` and output if *completely* (open-write-close) successful or not. I want also to write as few code as possible. It's about C++03.

Solution1 (seems optimal):

```
std::fstream file;
file.open("test.txt",std::ios_base::out); // sets failbit to true if open fails?
file << data; // what happens here if !file.is_open()?
file.close(); // and here? does close() work when writing data failed?
if (file)
    std::cout << "Success";
else
    std::cout << "Failed";

file.clear(); // for again usage. But what happens if file failed to open?
              // Or data failed to be written? Or file failed to be closed?
              // Is data waiting in stream to be written to next opened file?
```

Solution2:

```
std::fstream file;
file.open("test.txt",std::ios_base::out);
if (file.is_open())
{
    file << data;
    file.close();
}
if (file) // if only writing data fails, is failbit reset by close()?
    std::cout << "Success";
else
    std::cout << "Failed";

file.clear();
```

Solution3:

```
// is this solution overkill?

std::fstream file;
file.open("test.txt",std::ios_base::out);
if (file.is_open())
{
    file << data;
    if (!file)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed";
        file.clear();
    }
    file.close();
    if (file)
        std::cout << "Success";
    else
        std::cout << "Failed (again)";
}
else
    std::cout << "Failed";

file.clear();
```

Are they all equivalent and safe?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680698/c-reading-a-file-using-ifstream

Comment: @Csq I know what `file` and `!file` means, I only don't get the relation to `is_open()` and the concequences to `close()` and later reopening to write: similar when `double d; std::cin >> d; if (!std::cin) std::cout << "fail"; std::cin.clear(); char new_try; std::cin >> new_try;` and you enter "abcd": after `clear()` there is still "abcd" in the stream waiting to be written to `new_try` (only the 'a')...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any solution will actually be fairly complicated, because you'll
normally want to handle different types of errors differently.
If you cannot open the file, for example, you want to tell the
user that, and not just that the output failed.  Not being able
to open the file is an error that you really expect.  On the
other hand, if a write operation fails, you want a different
error handling.

Thus, I would recommend checking `is_open` immediately after
trying to open the file, and handling the error appropriately
then.

Later errors are far rarer, but probably more serious.  In many
cases, it's acceptable to only check for the error after the
close, but whenever an error occurs, you should probably delete
the partially written (and thus corrupt) file.  The same holds
if your program fails for some other reason when writing the
data: close the file and delete it.  (I tend to use an RAII
class for this, with a `commit` function which is called when
all of the output has finished.  The commit closes the file, and
if the close succeeds, sets a flag; if the flag is not set when
the destructor is called, the destructor closes the file,
ignoring any errors, and then deletes it.)

As for using `clear()`: I can't think of a case where I'd use it
on an output stream.  The iostream classes aren't designed for
reuse, and have far too much internal state to be easily reset.
On input, it can be useful, followed by ignore, if there was
a format error, but this consideration doesn't apply to output
streams, so I'd just ignore it.  (And of course, once you call
`clear`, you have no way of knowing whether anything which
preceded it succeeded or not.)

Comment: good arguments, but I want the user to let only know if the whole chain open-write-close succeeded - it should be his decision, if he deletes a maybe corrupted file (maybe there is some incomplete useful information in it, especially if he waited an algorithm to end for long time). And for output reuse: what if there is not enough hard-disk space. `<<` fails for some big data, for other smaller not. If in my above example `open(), << data, or close()` fail, I `clear()` the files state and reopen it, could there be still data waiting to be written (like when cin extraction fails)?

Comment: @mb84 If you really don't want to distinguish between failing to open and a later error, you don't have to.  With regards to the other scenarios, don't forget that the output is buffered, so the error may only occur on a later output.  If you wanted to make this work, you'd probably have to insert a lot of `flush`, and check after those.

Comment: @mb84 Output and input are not comparable here.  An extraction can fail because of a format error; this isn't possible for output.  In fact, once the file is successfully opened, about the only possible failure is a hard write failure to disk.

Comment: Ok, so my 1. solution would be fine, if I am interested in the success of open-write-close as unity? `close()` would implicitly `flush()`, so all right? But again, because it's not clear: when in my 1. solution `file << data` or when buffered flushing in `file.close()` fails (easy example: USB-stick pulled out between `open()` and `<<` or `close()`, *where* is data? Remains it in object `file` and is written to the next file I open? Would I have to use something like `ignore()` for `istream` before reusing `file`?

Comment: @mb84 If you eject a USB stick after a file is opened on it, but before the data is written to it, the data is lost.  It will not be written to the next file you open - it is gone.  You've created an exceptional case.  In that circumstance, attempting to write to the file would result in the errorbit (and likely the failbit) being set on the `ofstream` object.

Comment: @mb84 Where is the data?  It depends on whether it has already been flushed, and how the OS manages such things.  When writing, the data first goes to a local buffer; when it is flushed, it is transferred to the OS, and what happens after that doesn't concern C++ (as least as far as the standard is concerned).   Typically, the OS will also have an internal buffer, which will be synchronized with the media at some future time.  Typically too, a write will change some meta-data, which in some cases, won't be synchronized until after the final `close`.

Comment: Also, pulling out a USB-stick may corrupt the file system on it, so that not only the data you were writing, but other data as well may be lost.

Comment: @ZacHowland Actually, what happens is very system dependent.  The intent is that `badbit` (and no others) should be set.  But the naming conventions here are confusing: `std::ios_base::fail()` returns true if either `failbit` or `badbit` are set.

Comment: @ZacHowland and James Kanze. Thanks you both for good explanations! I will give the answer to James, because more detailed. But +1 to Zac too. As consequence I will really use `ofstream` in a separate, auto-destroying scope and don't reuse it...

Comment: Downvote because this does not answer the question at all.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to make this robust in as few lines as possible, this will probably get you about as close as you can:

```
std::ofstream file("test.txt");
if (file.is_open())
{
    if (file << data)
    {
        std::cout << "Success";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed";
    }
    file.close();
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Failed";
}
```

There is no need to call `clear()` for output streams.  Additionally, `<<` returns a reference to the `ofstream`, so you can check it in the if-condition instead of checking it afterwards.

If you wanted more descriptive error handling (e.g. handing of errors differently depending on what the error is), you would need more code.

Comment: Why there is no need to `clear()` output streams? They can fail. Or do later insertions with `<<` not be dependent of fail state?

Comment: If an output stream is in a failed state, clearing it would not change the fact that it was in such a state (though, it may cause larger problems).  For example, if the file fails to open, the failbit is set.  If you clear it, that doesn't open the file, but attempting to write to it will simply set the failbit again.  The only real use for `clear` on an output stream is if you attempted to use it for input (which would fail), and then wanted to continue ... but this isn't a *real* use case as it is poor coding instead of a runtime error that needs to be addressed.

Comment: I just want to reuse `file` for writing multiple files, that's why I need to use `clear()`. And I think it would also make sense when using it only for one file: `open()` fails because of read-only -> change this through OS, clear, and reopen. Or not enough hard disk space: `<<` or `close()` fails, free hard disk space through OS, clear, and rewrite. I don't understand what you mean by "if you attempted to use it for input (which would fail)"...

Comment: "I want to reuse `file` for writing multiple files" - you *can* do that, but I would caution you to not do that.  If you are writing multiple files, put the logic for each file write in a function, and write a loop that calls that function with the appropriate file name.  If `open` fails, you have to do a **lot** more code to properly handle the error (which is what I stated at the end of the answer), and in doing so you are not likely going to clear the state of a previous `ofstream` and attempt to write again - you are going to open the file with a new `ofstream` (cont.)

Comment: That is, unless you have a massively monolithic application, in which case you have other issues.  `clear` is an inherited function, but for `ostreams`, it is not all that useful.  These streams are intentionally not designed for reuse.

Comment: Ok I see, reusing is not the best idea... What about `ostringstream`? Is it legitimate to reuse it: `ostringstream tmp; tmp << bla; ... tmp.str(""); tmp << reuse;`?

Comment: @mb84 `std::ostringstream` provides a method `str(const char*)` to "reset" the internal data.  In effect, you are not "reusing" it, but rather changing the data and then continuing to use it.  That is fine, but your use case for doing so would be limited.

Comment: @ZacHowland How is clearing a stringstream, filling it with new data, and then using it again not reuse?  You're clearing the data of an already-initialized object and then reusing it, rather than initializing another instance?  Right?

Also, is this legitimate?  I feel like it would be poor practice just from a readability standpoint, but maybe it would be a slight optimization?

Comment: @ACK_stoverflow I would view that as improper usage of the word "reuse" in a software context.  Resetting the data is simply *continuing* to use the same instance.  Code reuse would imply it is in a function that gets called with a different parameter to output to a different file, for example.  Legitimate?  That is kind of open-ended.  It definitely makes the code less readable and harder to debug - and you are not likely to have any sort of code optimization happening because of it.  All-in-all, I would avoid resetting the stream to use it for a different purpose.